# Вывести нечетные слова в каждой строке через команду awk

Tags: linux

В упор не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i%2==1){printf $i " "}}printf "\n"}' data.txt
```

Для нетабличного текста:

```
printf "Quick ::brown -- :: fox-\n.Jumps++ over, the .lazy cat-dog" | \
awk 'gsub(/\s\W+|\W+\s|^\W+|\W+$/, " ")'0 | \
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i%2==1){printf $i " "}}printf "\n"}'
```

>

```
Quick fox
Jumps the cat-dog
```

Comment: Не будет работать в строках, где есть символ «тире» или ему подобные. Подсказка, во-первых, надо использовать `\w`.

Comment: @0andriy
да работает вроде:
echo "a-aa b-bb c" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i%2==1){printf $i " "}}printf "\n"}'

Вывод: a-aa c

Comment: "Тире" подразумевает пробельные символы (не путайте с дефисом): `Моя — не понимай твоя.` работает?